# Select a distinct combination of 2 columns and get the latest datetime row from the each distinctions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get rows by selecting a distinct combination of 2 columns("column_a" and "column_b" as below example) and get the latest datetime row for the result of each distinctions with one sql query in MySQL. It would be better to see sample data rather than to read my English.

**sample_table (Simplified the "created_datetime" column)**

```
id column_a column_b column_c created_datetime
-----------------------------------------
1 100 200 aaaa t
2 200 100 bbbb t+20
3 100 300 cccc t+40
4 100 200 zzzzzzz t+60
```

**My Ideal result**

```
id column_a column_b column_c created_datetime
-----------------------------------------
3 100 300 cccc t+40
4 100 200 zzzzzzz t+60
```

**Here is a few patterns I have tried:**

A:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    column_a,
    column_b,
    MAX(created_datetime)
FROM sample_table
GROUP BY column_a, column_b;
```

The result would be

```
100 200 t+60
100 300 t+40
200 100 t+20
```

B:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    least(column_a, column_b) as column_a,
    greatest(column_a, column_b) as column_b
FROM sample_table
GROUP BY column_a, column_b;
```

The result would be

```
100 200
100 300
```

C:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
least(column_a, column_b) as column_a,
    greatest(column_a, column_b) as column_b,
    MAX(created_datetime)
FROM sample_table
GROUP BY column_a, column_b;
```

The result would be

```
100 200 t+60
100 300 t+40
100 200 t+20
```

I am trying to get the result without any other languages like JavaScript or Python to tweak after it gets the data. Is it impossible to make this with one sql query or do I need to take a further step with MySQL? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your ideal result seems to be missing "2 200 100 bbbb t+20". You have 3 distinct examples in your sample_table based off of looking at both column_a and column_b for distictiveness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT sample_table.column_a,
       sample_table.column_b,
       sample_table.column_c,
       sample_table.created_datetime
FROM sample_table
     INNER JOIN (SELECT least(column_a, column_b) as column_a,
                        greatest(column_a, column_b) as column_b,
                        MAX(created_datetime) as created_datetime
                 FROM sample_table
                 GROUP BY least(column_a, column_b),
                          greatest(column_a, column_b)) t
     ON t.column_a = least(sample_table.column_a, sample_table.column_b)
     AND t.column_b = greatest(sample_table.column_a, sample_table.column_b)
     AND t.created_datetime = sample_table.created_datetime
```

Comment: Excellent. That's exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks a lot.